# type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' in a dynamic attribution of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```dart
child: Column(
  children: [
    Text(i.description),
    i.colors.map<Widget>(
    (colours) => CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(colors),
      value: i[colors],
      onChanged: (colors){
        setState(() {
          i[colors] = colors;
        });
      },
    ).toList()
   ],
  )
```

I want to show checkbuttons for each color present in each object, but it throws this error:

> type 'List < Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the error because `Column.children` expects a 'simple' array. But you gave an array with a `Text` AND another array (`i.colors.map<>(___).toList()`), so you got your error.

Add the **spread operator** `...` before your list, it will unwrap it :

```
child: Column(
  children: [
    Text(i.description),
    ...i.colors.map<Widget>(
    (colours) => CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(colors),
      value: i[colors],
      onChanged: (colors){
        setState(() {
          i[colors] = colors;
        });
      },
    ).toList()
   ],
  )
```